# Slow SQL deploy with bicep template

Tags: deployment, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy a sql server and sql database on azure using a bicep template but it's really slow, sometimes the result is a timeout exception.
This is the bicep template that i'm using:

```
param serverName string 
param sqlDBName string
param location string
@secure()
param administratorLoginPassword string

resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: serverName
  location: location
  properties: {
  administrators: {
  azureADOnlyAuthentication: false
  }
    administratorLogin: 'sqlAdmin'
    administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
  }
}

resource sqlDB 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: sqlDBName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
}
```

I expect the deploy time to be a maximum of 2-3 minutes.
The api version is the latest, as of today (2022-05-01).

Am i doing something wrong or am i missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by very slow ? but yeah it should not take long

Answer (score 0):

> Deploying a SQL server and SQL database on azure using a bicep template is really slow, sometimes the result is a timeout exception:

It is a transient issue that will go away on its own. There could be multiple reasons for the slow deployment.

*Major issues are listed below:*

1. Change the deployment region (`location`) to improve the deployment time because sometimes there could be an excessive load on the region you are deploying into. As a result of multiple deployments occurring in parallel across the Azure portal, there will be a timeout exception during deployment.
2. Check the quota/size of the SQL server and database you are deploying. Exceeding the size limit irrespective of subscription limit also causes the slow deployment.
3. As you mentioned, always check the latest API versions and use them for deployment.

*After checking the above, I tried below bicep code in my environment and the deployment was successful as shown below.*

```bash
param server string = 'mysqlserverj12'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource servername 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: server
  location: location
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: 'user1'
    administratorLoginPassword: 'xxxx'
    version: '12.0'
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    restrictOutboundNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
  }
}

resource Database 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  parent: servername
  name: 'mySamplejahDatabase'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'GP_S_Gen5'
    tier: 'GeneralPurpose'
    family: 'Gen5'
    capacity: 2
  }
  kind: 'v12.0,user,vcore,serverless'
  properties: {
    collation: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
    maxSizeBytes: 34359738368
    catalogCollation: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
    zoneRedundant: false
    readScale: 'Disabled'
    autoPauseDelay: 60
    requestedBackupStorageRedundancy: 'Geo'
    minCapacity: 2
    isLedgerOn: false
  }
}
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm doing cyclic deployments: i'm deploying a resource group containing the sql server and sql database, then i'm deleting it. Once it's deleted, i'm deploying another resource group with the sql server and sql database, then deleting it, and so on. The first time it takes a normal amount of time (2/3 minutes), the second time it take 5 minutes, then 8, then 10, and it keeps growing until timeout

Comment: Wait until the deletion process of a resource completed. Sometimes after we raise a delete process request for a resource, system might take some time to process and delete it. And also check if any other deployments are running parallelly in same environment. @ADellaPosta

Comment: I'm already doing it.. In my resource group i also have other resources (service app, keyvault, ecc...) so when i'm deleting the resource group, i'm also deleting those resources but the only ones that take more and more time are the sql server and sql database. If the problem is that i'm not waiting enough time between deployments, shouldn't it occur with every resource?

Comment: Can you [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/723847/azure-sql-database-deployment-fails-with-bicep-set) this once. @ADellaPosta

Comment: You can also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76313670/guidance-on-long-running-azure-deployments). @ADellaPosta